# Extracting a red color and its area from an image using CV2

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an image from a simulation I performed (the image is attached). I want to contour the red coulour in the center of plate and calculate its area considering that the plate is with dimensions of 1X1 cm.

[image]

I have tried doing it myself using Python and OpenCV but have failed. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Threshold on red using cv2.inRange()

Comment: Note that you don't really need to contour it to find its area. You can just count the pixels matched by `cv2.inRange()` and divide by the total known (blue) area to get the proportion of red ones.

Comment: "I have tried" should always be followed by _what_ you tried, _how_ you tried (code), and _what happened_ (outputs). [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you'll want a **"mask"**.

Then you can count the number of elements in the mask.

```py
image = ...
(height, width) = image.shape[:2]

hsv = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
# hue, saturation, value
# the red area is well saturated and very bright

# red is near 0 degrees of hue
# since we're on a circle, those values might span 340 to 20 degrees
# hues are mapped into 0..180 (uint8) for 0..360 degrees
# we need two ranges because we're spanning across 0 from both sides and inRange() can't handle that at once

mask1 = cv.inRange(hsv, (170, 128, 128), (180, 255, 255)) # pinkish red
mask2 = cv.inRange(hsv, (  0, 128, 128), ( 10, 255, 255)) # yellowish red

mask = mask1 | mask2

red_count = cv.countNonZero(mask)
fraction = red_count / (width * height)
print(f"{fraction:.2%}")
# 0.76%
```

Yes, that's correct. 0.76%. It's not much area.

This is the mask calculated on a crop of your picture:

[image: mask]

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the upper range and lower range of the colour red.
2. Use cv2.inRange() to get a black and white mask. [The link to use inRange function](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html)
3. Now that you have a mask, use cv2.findContours to get the required contours and while iterating, get the area by using cv2.contourArea()